# F# Parameterized Insert Sql

Tags: f#

Trying to understand how to parameterize query with `SqlCommandProvider`. So far I've got this

```
[<Literal>]
let connectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQL2019;Initial Catalog=MyDb;Trusted_Connection=True;"

type InsertCommand = 
    SqlCommandProvider<"INSERT INTO Category (Name, Value, Website) VALUES (@name, @value, @website)", connectionString, SingleRow = true>

let cmdInsert = new InsertCommand()

let insertCategories (data: seq<string * string>) =
    data
    |> Seq.iter
        (
            fun x ->
                cmdInsert.Execute(name = fst x, value = Int32.Parse(snd x), website = "www.example.com") |> ignore
        )
```

But on the line `new InsertCommand()` I'm getting this error

```
The member or object constructor 'SqlCommandProvider,CommandText="...",ConnectionStringOrName="...",SingleRow="True"'
 does not take 0 argument(s). An overload was found taking 2 arguments
```

Can someone please explain? If not, can someone please give an example on how to do parameterized insert query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is telling you that the you are missing an argument for the constructor of the provided type, i.e. your `InsertCommand` type. I do not have a SQL database to try this, but the type provided by `SqlCommandProvider` should have an overload that takes a connection string and (optionally) a timeout.

The following should do the trick:

```
let cmdInsert = new InsertCommand(connectionString)
```